# Django AttributeError 'CreateUserForm' object has no attribute 'username'

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create user registration page, to do so, I use default UserCreationForm. I want to register users through their phone numbers, so I changed this form like this:

```
class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    restriction = RegexValidator(r'^[0-9]*$')
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=11, validators=[restriction])
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'password1', 'password2']
```

There is part of registration view function:

```
if form.is_valid():
    #save form and redirect
elif len(form.cleaned_data['password1']) < 8:
    messages.error(request, 'Password is too short')
elif form.cleaned_data['username'].isnumeric() == False:
    messages.error(request, 'Enter valid phone number!')
```

So if the form turns out to be invalid, it checks whether password or phone number is wrong but when it comes to checking phone, it returns "KeyError at /registration/" and "Exception Value: 'username'".
If I change form.cleaned_data['username'] to form.username, it returns "Django AttributeError 'CreateUserForm' object has no attribute 'username'"

I genuinely don't know what to do and why this error is even a thing.

Comment: Try using `form.cleaned_data.get('username', '')`. Also since the key is missing you might not actually be sending the data from the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Abdul Aziz Barkat said,

> form.cleaned_data.get('username', '')

actually is the solution.